# Yeoman & Rails app: using grunt-rev task to revision shared assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yeoman, gruntjs

I have a Rails app which is not using the asset pipeline. The assets are managed by Yeoman (http://yeoman.io/) and Grunt tasks. We recently introduced a browser cache busting task called `grunt-rev` to revision the assets before deploying. This task re-names the assets with some uniqueness, then flow passes on to another task called `grunt-usemin` which updates the html and css files with the new asset names before copying them to the public folder.

For example, `main.css` in `index.html` looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

And will be re-witten to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/f43ce6bf.main.css">
```

---

The Rails app works fine with local development as the assets are dynamically generated by Yeoman. But once deployed, the assets public folder contains all the revved assets and the Rails views (written in haml) cannot find them. Links like the one below are now dead...

```
%link{:href => "/styles/main.css", :media => "screen,print", :rel => "stylesheet"}
```

So I've come up with a few ideas I think might work.

1. Symlink `main.css` -> `f43ce6bf.main.css`
2. Add a view helper to find the assets
3. Inline the javascript & css into the view as it is not too big
4. Fork grunt-usemin to add haml support, then run it against the views within Rails

But am not sure whats best? or am I missing a much easier solution?

UPDATE: I'm now using the helper like below

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def busted_css
    @busted_css ||= begin
      if Rails.env != "development"
        File.join("/styles",
          File.basename(Dir["public/styles/*main.css"].sort_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}.reverse[0])
        )
      else
        "/styles/main.css"
      end
    end
  end
end
```